# I have this small table having duplicate id and names and I want to replace null values with names using there ID

Tags: sql, oracle, join

[image: There is some null values at name column and I want to relace null to names matching with ID]

I got it with self join:

```
select a.id, a.name, b.id, b.name, nvl(a.name,b.name)
from names a
join names b
on a.id = b.id
where a.name is null and b.name is not null;
```

But don't no how do I update it in the table.
I tried update statement but did not work

[image: This is what output look like]
[]

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Please in code questions give a [mre]. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: Whatever you are stuck on here, when you have a [mre], it will (clearly) be duplicate beginner question. [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/3404097) [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) Please before considering posting read the manual/reference & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that there are no unique [id, name] combinations in rows that don't have empty `name` columns.

```
SQL> select * From test;

        ID NAME
---------- ------
         1 naya
         1 naya
         2 amar
         3 dhruv           --> here
         4 shyla
         4 shyla
         3 diya            --> here
         5 ananya
         6 ishaan
         5
         2
         2
         1
         3

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```

So, which name would you want to get for ID = 3? You can't have both, so - one option is to select *any*, e.g. max.

```
SQL> update test a set
  2    a.name = (select max(b.name)
  3              from test b
  4              where b.id = a.id
  5             )
  6  where a.name is null;

5 rows updated.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * From test;

        ID NAME
---------- ------
         1 naya
         1 naya
         2 amar
         3 dhruv
         4 shyla
         4 shyla
         3 diya
         5 ananya
         6 ishaan
         5 ananya
         2 amar
         2 amar
         1 naya
         3 diya

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you its working and 4th row is my mistake while creating sample table for this query

Answer (score 0):

From Oracle 12, you can use:

```sql
UPDATE names n
SET    name = (SELECT name
               FROM   names x
               WHERE  x.id = n.id
               ORDER BY name NULLS LAST
               FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY)
WHERE  name IS NULL
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=687187d90c44aad8330aef3fa1d714c4)*